# Utilizar os operadores AND e OR na mesma condicional

Tags: php

No exemplo a seguir a verificação não funciona se a pagina foi a `sobre`, nesse caso ele exibe a página `servicos` mesmo não sendo ela a requisitada na validação. O que tem de errado? eu percebi que esse problema só acontece no `elseif`

```
$status = 1;
$pagina = "sobre";

if($pagina = "home" AND $status == 2 OR $status == 3) {

    echo "Página Home";

}elseif($pagina = "servicos" AND $status == 1 OR $status == 2) {

    echo "Página Serviços";

}elseif($pagina = "sobre" AND $status == 1 OR $status == 2) {

    echo "Página Serviços";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> nesse caso ele exibe a página servicos

Repare que em `$pagina = "home"` você está **atribuindo** o a string `home` para a variável `$pagina`!

Para comparações, o operador é `==` (Compara o valor) ou `===` (Compara o tipo e valor).

Sua condição deveria ser mudada também:

```
if($pagina == "home" AND ($status == 2 OR $status == 3)) { // ...
```

**Concluindo, seu código deveria estar assim:**

```
$status = 1;
$pagina = "sobre";

if($pagina == "home" AND ($status == 2 OR $status == 3)) {  // PAGINA DEVE SER "home" E STATUS DEVE SER 2 OU 3

    echo "Página Home";

} else if($pagina == "servicos" AND ($status == 1 OR $status == 2)) { // PAGINA DEVE SER "servicos" E STATUS DEVE SER 1 OU 2

    echo "Página Serviços";

} else if($pagina == "sobre" AND ($status == 1 OR $status == 2)) { // PAGINA DEVE SER "home" E STATUS DEVE SER 1 OU 2

    echo "Página Serviços"; // Página Sobre!!!

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, já me deparei com esse tipo de problema varias vezes e sempre tinha que arrumar meios alternativos para resolver